# Informix sql select from table to another table with more values

Tags: sql, informix

I have a temp table with id, name, surname, comment and I want to select all that information and add it to a table which has id, name, surname, comment, date, code. how would i insert it into the table from the temp table and make all date = TODAY and all code=001?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't own any Informix server so I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
INSERT the_table (id, name, surname, comment, date, code)
SELECT id, name, surname, comment, TODAY, '001'
FROM temp_table
```

This assumes that the `code`is a character field; you will have to adjust the query according to your specific database schema. If the date field is a datetime change `TODAY` to `CURRENT`